# Creating a toolbar in C++

Tags: c++, toolbar

I'm trying to create a toolbar in C++. I want the toolbar to contain different icons that when clicked will allow a different tool to be implemented.

I've learnt how to read / write bitmap files, whereby I specify the width, height and colours and the image is created. However I'm not sure how to / if it is a good choice to use this method to try and create the toolbar?

If it is, then does anyone have any guidance on how to create the toolbar? I can't find much when searching online.

Thanks.

Comment: What IDE are you using? C++ Builder, QT, Visual studio?

Comment: C++ does not contain graphic libraries, and I doubt you want to access video directly; I think you question is more about using a graphical framework than C++ insn't it?

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio as the editor. @OznOg a colleague suggested the idea of using bitmaps to create the toolbar and other images, then can load them when the program starts. But I'm a bit stuck on how to create the necessary images with this method. I have some basic experience with SDL2 if that could be used (but would have no idea where to start). I'm a total novice really.